# PyQGIS import from UI class problem

Tags: pyqgis, python-2.7

I've tried to build a plugin from scratch to better understand the plugin structure and so on without the help of PluginBuilder or similar tools so my code could contain flaws. I went through every step by logic and I'm not sure about my structure.

Everything works fine until in the "run()" method of my main file(which Its name is ZVC.py) I try to import objects from my UI file(which Its name is ZVC_form.py).

In the "run()" method I want to import the ComboBoxes and fill them with open layers but it won't recognize my imported objects and it gives out "AttributeError: ZVC instance has no attribute 'comboBoxVector'" error.

Here is my structure:

```
main directory/
     ZVC.py   #main file
     ZVC_form.py   #pyuic4, generated python version of the UI file
```

Here is my Main file:(ZVC.py)(the problem lies in the last sentence of this file!)

```
from qgis.PyQt.QtGui import *
from qgis.PyQt.QtWidgets import *
import qgis
from ZVC_form import Ui_Form
import sys
import os

# initialize Qt resources from file resources.py
icon_path = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__))+"/icon.png"

class ZVC:

  def __init__(self, iface):
    # save reference to the QGIS interface
    self.iface = iface
    self.Form = QWidget()
    Ui_Form().setupUi(self.Form)

  def initGui(self):
    # create action that will start plugin configuration
    self.action = QAction(QIcon(icon_path),  'Zonal Visibility Coverage'  , self.iface.mainWindow())
    self.action.setObjectName("Button")
    self.action.setWhatsThis("Configuration for test plugin")
    self.action.setStatusTip("This is status tip")
    self.action.triggered.connect(self.run)

    # add toolbar button and menu item
    self.iface.addToolBarIcon(self.action)
    self.iface.addPluginToMenu("&Zonal Visibility Coverage", self.action)

  def unload(self):
    # remove the plugin menu item and icon
    self.iface.removePluginMenu("&Zonal Visibility Coverage", self.action)
    self.iface.removeToolBarIcon(self.action)

  def run(self):

    # create and show a configuration dialog or something similar
    # show the dialog

    self.Form.show()
    Ui_Form.comboBox_vector.addItem("whatever") #this is the problem
```

and my UI file:(ZVC_form.py)

```
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui
import core

try:
    _fromUtf8 = QtCore.QString.fromUtf8
except AttributeError:
    def _fromUtf8(s):
        return s

try:
    _encoding = QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8
    def _translate(context, text, disambig):
        return QtGui.QApplication.translate(context, text, disambig, _encoding)
except AttributeError:
    def _translate(context, text, disambig):
        return QtGui.QApplication.translate(context, text, disambig)


#This is the Class which let you to have a clickable QLineEdit
class LineEdit(QtGui.QLineEdit):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(LineEdit, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.flag = False

    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        if not self.flag:
            self.clear()
        self.flag = True
        self.setStyleSheet("color: rgb(0,0,0);")
        QtGui.QLineEdit.mousePressEvent(self, event)

class Ui_Form(object):
    def setupUi(self, Form):
        Form.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("Form"))
        Form.resize(514, 300)
        Form.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(514, 300))
        Form.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(514, 300))

        self.lineEdit_refrac = LineEdit(Form)
        self.lineEdit_refrac.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(140, 235, 361, 20))
        self.lineEdit_refrac.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("lineEdit_refrac"))
        self.lineEdit_refrac.setStyleSheet(_fromUtf8("color: rgb(120,120,120);"))
        self.lineEdit_refrac.setText("0.14285")

        self.label_refrac = QtGui.QLabel(Form)
        self.label_refrac.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 235, 111, 16))
        self.label_refrac.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("label_refrac"))

        self.label_input = QtGui.QLabel(Form)
        self.label_input.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 177, 81, 16))
        self.label_input.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("label_input"))

        self.label_vector = QtGui.QLabel(Form)
        self.label_vector.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("label_vector"))
        self.label_vector.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 207, 111, 16))

        self.comboBox_vector = QtGui.QComboBox(Form)
        self.comboBox_vector.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(140, 205, 361, 20))
        self.comboBox_vector.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("comboBox_vector"))

        self.lineEdit_output = QtGui.QLineEdit(Form)
        self.lineEdit_output.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(78, 261, 261, 20))
        self.lineEdit_output.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("lineEdit_output"))

        self.button_close_ok = QtGui.QDialogButtonBox(Form)
        self.button_close_ok.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(341, 256, 161, 30))
        self.button_close_ok.setAutoFillBackground(False)
        self.button_close_ok.setStandardButtons(QtGui.QDialogButtonBox.Close | QtGui.QDialogButtonBox.Ok)
        self.button_close_ok.setCenterButtons(False)
        self.button_close_ok.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("button_close_ok"))

        self.comboBox_input = QtGui.QComboBox(Form)
        self.comboBox_input.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(140, 175, 361, 20))
        self.comboBox_input.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("comboBox_input"))

        self.button_output = QtGui.QToolButton(Form)
        self.button_output.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(8, 260, 61, 22))
        self.button_output.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("button_output"))

        self.farme_logo = QtGui.QFrame(Form)
        self.farme_logo.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 511, 171))
        self.farme_logo.setStyleSheet("image: url(C:/Users/ash/.qgis2/python/plugins/ZVC/Logo.png);")
        self.farme_logo.setFrameShape(QtGui.QFrame.StyledPanel)
        self.farme_logo.setFrameShadow(QtGui.QFrame.Raised)
        self.farme_logo.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("farme_logo"))

        self.retranslateUi(Form)
        QtCore.QObject.connect(self.button_close_ok, QtCore.SIGNAL(_fromUtf8("accepted()")), lambda: self.intInput(Form)  )
        self.button_close_ok.rejected.connect(Form.close)  # This is the new form of connecting Singnals to Slots.
        self.button_output.clicked.connect(lambda: self.FileSave(Form))  # When you have set arguments such af "Form" in the function and want to call it with () at the end use lambda!
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Form)
        Form.setTabOrder(self.comboBox_input, self.lineEdit_refrac)
        Form.setTabOrder(self.lineEdit_refrac, self.button_output)
        Form.setTabOrder(self.button_output, self.lineEdit_output)
        Form.setTabOrder(self.lineEdit_output, self.button_close_ok)

    def retranslateUi(self, Form):
        Form.setWindowTitle(_translate("Form", "Zonal Visibility Coverage", None))
        self.lineEdit_refrac.setText(_translate("Form", "0.14286", None))
        self.label_input.setText(_translate("Form", "Input Raster", None))
        self.label_refrac.setText(_translate("Form", "Refraction Coefficient", None))
        self.button_output.setText(_translate("Form", "Output", None))
        self.label_vector.setText("Input Shape")

    def FileSave(self, Form):
        self.fileTypes = "TIFF format (*.tif);;Band interleaved by line (*.BIL);;Bitmap Image (*.BMP)"
        self.name = QtGui.QFileDialog.getSaveFileName(filter = self.fileTypes)
        self.lineEdit_output.setText(self.name)

    def intInput(self, Form):
        try:
            if self.lineEdit_output.text() == "":
                self.lineEdit_refrac.setText("Please choose an output direction")
            else:
                float(self.lineEdit_refrac.text())
                Form.lower()
                core.process()
        except ValueError:
            self.lineEdit_refrac.setText("Please fill only with numbers!")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah, I forgot to initialize UI_form! An easy thing to miss!

By doing `self.UI = Ui_Form()` at `__init__` method of the main file and do the rest by using `Self.UI` the problem will be gone!

like `self.UI.comboBox_vector.addItem("whatever")` instead of `Ui_Form.comboBox_vector.addItem("whatever")`.

The worst nightmares will happen if you are unable to debug your code in the IDE :(